# How to manage selected variables for listtiles inside of a listview.builder

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a `ListView.builder` which returns a `ListTile`. The `itemCount` is set to `min(_selectedEvents.length, 3)`. So a maximum of 3 `ListTile`s is being returned with a `backgroundColor` of `Colors.grey[200]`.

I want to set the color to `Colors.red` for a single `ListTile` when it is pressed. I set selected: `_selectedListtileController` (a `var` that I created) and with `onTap` this is being set to true, which changes the color to red.

But the problem is that the red color is set for all the `ListTile`s and not for a single one. Also creating 3 separate controllers is not an option because I return them in a `ListTile` and I can only pass 1 controller.

How do I set the color of a separate `ListTile` whenever the `ListTile` is pressed?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an empty map at the top of the class

```
  final _isSelected = Map();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
```

on your ListView.builder

```
ListView.builder(
        itemCount: _selectedEvents.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {

          //add this line to initiate             
          if (!_isSelected.containsKey(index)) // important
              _isSelected[index] = false;

          return ListTile(
            ...
            ...
            
            // and this line to check listTile is selected or not
            selected: _isSelected[index],
            tileColor: Colors.grey[200],
            selectedTileColor: Colors.red,
            onTap: () {
              setState(() => _isSelected[index] = !_isSelected[index] );
            },
          );
        },
      ),
```

or you can create your selected logic at initState()

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like more than one `ListTile` to be selectable, we could define a `List<int>` where to save the `indexes` of selected `ListTile`s:

```
// StatefulWidget is required
List<int> _selectedTiles = [];
```

And use the following functions to toggle the selected state of a specific `ListTile`:

```
void toggleSelectedListTile(int index) {
    if (_selectedTiles.contains(index))
       setState(() => _selectedTiles.remove(index));
    else
       setState(() => _selectedTiles.add(index));
}
```

A `ListTile` `Widget` has the `selected` property, which we can take advantage of:

```
ListTile(
 selected: _selectedTiles.contains(index),
 selectedTileColor: Colors.red,
 title: Text('List tile $index'),
 onTap() { toggleSelectedListTile(index); },
)
```

Therefore, a full example snippet of this solution would be:

```
class HomeWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  HomeWidget({ Key key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeWidgetState createState() => _StatefulWidgetExampleState();
}


class _HomeWidgetState extends State<StatefulWidgetExample> {

   List<int> _selectedTiles = [];

   void toggleSelectedListTile(int index) {
       if (_selectedTiles.contains(index))
          setState(() => _selectedTiles.remove(index));
       else
          setState(() => _selectedTiles.add(index));
   }

   Widget _buildListTile(int index) {
      return ListTile(
       selected: _selectedTiles.contains(index),
       selectedTileColor: Colors.red,
       title: Text('List tile $index'),
       onTap() { toggleSelectedListTile(index); },
      );
   }

   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context)
      return Scaffold(
         body: new ListView.builder
            (
              itemCount: 3, 
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) => _buildListTile(index),
            ),
      );
}
```